# How to make static resources cached in browser tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7, browser-cache

I am trying to put static resources in browser cache ,On researching i got to know about ExpiresFilter , so I configured it like below in deployment descriptor.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
        <param-value>access plus 2 weeks</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
        <param-value>access plus 2 weeks</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
        <param-value>access plus 2 weeks</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But when i see any static resource say main.css the response header is like below

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:47146
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Wed, 15 Mar 2017 10:34:09 GMT
ETag:W/"47146-1489142922357"
Expires:0
Last-Modified:Fri, 10 Mar 2017 10:48:42 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

So it is not saving into browser cache.What could be the reason ?

Comment: If you want any further details tell me i will post that

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because i am using spring security in my application .so it is overriding the response headers so after i disabled the cache control header from spring security it is working.